# Quill text editor is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

Following the [Quill Quickstart guide](https://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/), I am trying to use the Quill text editor.

Below is the code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.6/quill.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
    <script>
      var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        theme: 'snow'
      });
    </script>

    <style>
      #editor-container {
        height: 375px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Create the editor container -->
    <div id="editor">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
      <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
      <p><br></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I am not getting expected output. The output I am getting is this:

> Hello World!
>
> Some initial **bold** text

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why you add jquery twice ? Jquery mini and jquery not minified ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to initialize the Quill editor after you have created the container (`<div id="editor">`).

On a side note, I would suggest checking the developer console before posting the next time you run into problems. It's of invaluable help.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.6/quill.js"></script>
  <style>
  #editor {
    height: 375px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Create the editor container -->
  <div id="editor">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
    <p><br></p>
  </div>

  <!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
  <script>
    var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
      theme: 'snow'
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. it worked for me. I have another question for this - using image link, how do I save image to database?

Comment: Are you asking how to do some more actions at the same time as you click 'image' in the quill toolbar? Look into creating a custom handler for that event. http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're including Quill's scripts several times.

Try starting from the example in the [quickstart guide...](http://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/)

```
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.6/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried removing duplicates, I have updated code in question. Still output doesn't change.